# child_process - windowsHide not working with detached: true

Tags: node.js

In the below example, I want to respawn a node process with detached = true which will spawn another process of procdump. In this case, the window is popping out and I don't want this happening.
I've put windowsHide flag on true but is not working.

Could you please help me?

Example:
==nodeSpawn.js file

```
let child_process = require("child_process");
const nodePath = "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe";
child_process.spawn(nodePath,['procDumpSpawn.js'],{
detached: true, //=>is working without detached true
stdio: 'ignore',
shell: false,
windowsHide: true
});
```

==procDumpSpawn.js file

```
let child_process = require("child_process");
const procDumpPath = "C:\procdump.exe";
child_process.spawn(procDumpPath, ['notepad'],{
stdio: 'ignore',
});
```

Run: node nodeSpawn.js

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21825